# How to enable Apache Tuscany SDO with OSGi container? [classloader issue]

Tags: osgi, classloader, apache-servicemix, sdo, apache-tuscany

I try to use Apache CXF in Apache ServiceMix with SDO. SDOs are provided with Apache Tuscany SDO implementation.

Here is the dependency map:

My osgi-bundle exposes a web service, bundle depends on SDO.

CXF system bundle depends on SDO too.

I installed Apache Tuscany SDO bundle stack as follows:

```
osgi:install -s mvn:org.apache.tuscany.sdo/tuscany-sdo-api-r2.1/1.1.1
osgi:install -s mvn:org.apache.tuscany.sdo/tuscany-sdo-impl/1.1.1
osgi:install -s mvn:org.apache.tuscany.sdo/tuscany-sdo-lib/1.1.1
osgi:install -s mvn:org.apache.tuscany.sdo/tuscany-sdo-tools/1.1.1
```

Start levels are:

```
...
tuscany-sdo-api-r2.1              28
tuscany-sdo-impl                  28
tuscany-sdo-lib                   28
tuscany-sdo-tools                 28

Apache CXF Bundle Jar (2.4.6)     30
camel-cxf (2.8.5)                 50
camel-cxf-transport (2.8.5)       50
...
MyApplication                     60
```

Whe I restart the server I get the folowwing exception printed:

```
karaf@root> Exception in thread "SpringOsgiExtenderThread-4" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'iws': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1420)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:192)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
        at org.springframework.osgi.context.support.AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.access$1600(AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.java:69)
        at org.springframework.osgi.context.support.AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext$4.run(AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.java:355)
        at org.springframework.osgi.util.internal.PrivilegedUtils.executeWithCustomTCCL(PrivilegedUtils.java:85)
        at org.springframework.osgi.context.support.AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.completeRefresh(AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.java:320)
        at org.springframework.osgi.extender.internal.dependencies.startup.DependencyWaiterApplicationContextExecutor$CompleteRefreshTask.run(DependencyWaiterApplicationContextExecutor.java:132)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at org.apache.cxf.sdo.SDODataBinding.initialize(SDODataBinding.java:128)
        at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.AbstractServiceFactoryBean.initializeDataBindings(AbstractServiceFactoryBean.java:86)
        at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.buildServiceFromClass(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:444)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.support.JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.buildServiceFromClass(JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.java:685)
        at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.initializeServiceModel(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:507)
        at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.create(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:241)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.support.JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.create(JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.java:205)
        at org.apache.cxf.frontend.AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.createEndpoint(AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.java:101)
        at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ServerFactoryBean.create(ServerFactoryBean.java:157)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsServerFactoryBean.create(JaxWsServerFactoryBean.java:203)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.getServer(EndpointImpl.java:433)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.doPublish(EndpointImpl.java:322)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.publish(EndpointImpl.java:239)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.publish(EndpointImpl.java:509)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeCustomInitMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1544)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1485)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1417)
        ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.tuscany.sdo.api.SDOUtil.<clinit>(SDOUtil.java:48)
        ... 35 more
```

As I can see in the source code of org.apache.tuscany.sdo.api.SDOUtil.java ([link](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/org/apache/tuscany/sdo/api/SDOUtil.java.html)):

```
46   public final class SDOUtil
47   {
48     protected static SDOHelper defaultSDOHelper = ((HelperProviderBase)HelperProvider.INSTANCE).sdoHelper();
49   ...
```

SDOUtil class from *tuscany-sdo-api-r2.1* depends on a helper class commonj.sdo.impl.HelperProvider.java.

Source code for HelperProvider.java ([link](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/commonj/sdo/impl/HelperProvider.java.html))

```
64       static {
65           // initialize the default instance using this class's classloader
66           // set to null if none could be located (implies no default implementation)
67           HelperProvider provider;
68           try {
69               provider = getInstance(HelperProvider.class.getClassLoader());
70           } catch (NoHelperProviderException e) {
71               provider = null;
72           }
73           INSTANCE = provider;
74       }
```

This means that getInstance() method does not work properly.

**How to make SDOHelper to get initialized correctly in an OSGi contained?**

**UPDATE**

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <!-- Generated by Apache ServiceMix Archetype -->

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.bssys</groupId>
    <artifactId>eg-smx-osgi-bundle</artifactId>
    <packaging>bundle</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Apache ServiceMix :: Camel OSGi Bundle</name>

    <properties>
       <camel.version>2.8.3</camel.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- CXF SDO -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-databinding-sdo</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Apache tuscany SDO -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tuscany.sdo</groupId>
            <artifactId>tuscany-sdo-api-r2.1</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tuscany.sdo</groupId>
            <artifactId>tuscany-sdo-impl</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tuscany.sdo</groupId>
            <artifactId>tuscany-sdo-lib</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tuscany.sdo</groupId>
            <artifactId>tuscany-sdo-tools</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <defaultGoal>install</defaultGoal>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.6</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <instructions>
                        <Bundle-SymbolicName>${project.artifactId}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                        <Import-Package>*,org.apache.camel.osgi</Import-Package>
                        <Private-Package>com.bssys</Private-Package>
                    </instructions>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

camel-context.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Generated by Apache ServiceMix Archetype -->
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:osgi="http://camel.apache.org/schema/osgi"
       xmlns:osgix="http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi-compendium"
       xmlns:ctx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd
       http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd
       http://camel.apache.org/schema/osgi http://camel.apache.org/schema/osgi/camel-osgi.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi-compendium http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi-compendium/spring-osgi-compendium.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
       http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd
">

  <osgi:camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <route>
      <from uri="timer://myTimer?fixedRate=true&amp;period=10000"/>
      <bean ref="myTransform" method="transform"/>
      <to uri="log:ExampleRouter"/>
    </route>
  </osgi:camelContext>

  <bean id="myTransform" class="com.bssys.MyTransform">
    <property name="prefix" value="${prefix}"/>
  </bean>

  <osgix:cm-properties id="preProps" persistent-id="com.bssys">
      <prop key="prefix">MyTransform</prop>
  </osgix:cm-properties>

  <ctx:property-placeholder properties-ref="preProps" />

    <!-- HTTP Endpoint -->
    <jaxws:endpoint xmlns:iws="http://www.bssys.com/SMEV/IWS/1"
        id="iws" address="/iws1"
        serviceName="iws:IWSExport_BaseImportIWSHttpService"
        endpointName="iws:IWSExport_BaseImportIWSHttpPort"
        implementor="com.bssys.smev.iws._1.BaseImportIWSImpl">
        <!-- 
        <jaxws:features>
            <bean class="org.apache.cxf.feature.LoggingFeature" />
        </jaxws:features>
         -->
    </jaxws:endpoint>



<!-- 
<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <route/>
</camelContext>
 -->

 </beans>
```

Comment: I found in tuscany-sdo-impl/MANIFEST.MF

    Export-Package: commonj.sdo.impl

and in tuscany-sdo-api/MANIFEST.MF

    Import-Package: commonj.sdo.impl;version="2.1"

also class **commonj.sdo.impl.HelperProvider** is visible for tuscany-sdo-api. Could you please provide spring configuration files?

Comment: I re-checked the jars and fixed the question. HelperProvider really lives inside _tuscany-sdo-api-r2.1_, i was wrong initially.

Comment: I will attach my pom.xml and spring.xml to the question.

Comment: Looks like OSGi service for HelperProvider implementation declared in META-INF\services\commonj.sdo.impl.HelperProvider was not created. Please type **status** in osgi console to make sure that OSGi service started correctly (it may even need to start manually).

Comment: I tried both _karaf@root> osgi:status_ and _karaf@root> status_ in console. None of them work. It says _Command not found: osgi:status_.

Comment: I type name of this command for Eqinox. Sorry I don't know which command equivalent on ServiceMix. Try osgi:help maybe it helps